# Maximum call stack size execeeded in socket.io

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

There are two pages, mario.html and index.html. index.html has inside of it an iframe of mario.html.

index.html code:

```
const socket = io();

function createId(){
    var id=''    
    var characters ='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    for (let count = 0; count < 7; count++) {
        id=id+characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length))
    }
    return id
}

function createRoom() {
   let id=createId() 
   alert(`Share this link:http://${location.host}/mario.html?room=${id}`)
    socket.emit('create room',id)
    isHost=true
}
setInterval(() => {
    socket.emit('host update things',game.solids,game.characters,game.scenery)
}, 1000);
```

mario.html code:

```
const socket = io();

function createId(){
    var id=''    
    var characters ='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    for (let count = 0; count < 7; count++) {
        id=id+characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length))
    }
    return id
}

function createRoom() {
   let id=createId() 
    alert(`Share this link:http://${location.host}/mario.html?room=${id}`)
    socket.emit('create room',id)
}

socket.emit('join room',location.search.split('room=')[1])    

socket.on('server update things',(serverSolids,serverCharacters,serverScenery)=>{
    console.log(serverCharacters)
    solids=serverSolids
    characters=serverCharacters
    scenery=serverScenery
})
```

server.js:

```
// Setup basic express server
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var rooms=[]

// Routing
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'view')));

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

function Room(host,id) {
  this.id=id
  this.host=host
  this.players=[host]
}

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('create room', (id) => {
    var room=new Room(socket.id,id)
    socket.join(room.id)
    rooms.push(room)
  })
  socket.on('join room',(roomId)=>{
    var room=rooms.find((item)=>{
      return item.id==roomId
    })
    if(room){
      socket.join(roomId)              ,
      room.players.push(socket.id)
    }else{
      console.log(room)
    }
  })
  socket.on('log',()=>{
    var room=io.sockets.adapter.rooms
    console.log('rooms:',room);
    console.log('rooms:',rooms) 
  })

  socket.on('host update things',(solids,characters,scenery)=>{
    room=rooms.find((item)=>{
      return item.host==socket.id
    })
    console.log(room)
    socket.broadcast.to(room.id).emit('server upate things',solids,characters,scenery)
  })

  socket.on('disconnecting',()=>{
    rooms.forEach((item,index)=>{
      if(item.players.includes(socket.id)){
        item.players.splice(index,1)
      }
    }) 
  })
  console.log('user connected')
})
```

When I run the server and open the index.html page, the console show:

> is-binary.js:28 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

(there isn't an is-binary.js file in my  project)

Comment: Did you try to remove 'setInterval' function and see if this problem is resolved?

Comment: yes, if i romve it, the problem is resolved

Comment: why do you need this interval? Do you still have a question or you are set?

Comment: it's to send the game state of the client to the server,  i can't see a better  option, (if i send the game state every single event, the page have the same probleme)